# Use drawer to switch between multiple Navigators in react-native

Tags: ios, navigation, react-native, drawer

I want to create a Drawer Menu on iOS that acts like Tabs so that each menu item displays a unique Navigation stack, that (in best case) also is persistent when switching between the different sections.
So far I have a simple drawer (using https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-drawer-layout)

```
<DrawerLayout
  ref="drawer"
  drawerBackgroundColor="#fff"
  drawerPosition={ DrawerLayout.positions.Right }
  drawerWidth={ 100 }
  renderNavigationView={ () => navigationView } >

  { contentView() }

</DrawerLayout>
```

The drawer itself displays some links which, when tapped, should change the content that is displayed in the main view:

```
navigationView() {
  return (
    <View style={ styles.drawer }>
      <MenuItem
        title="Home"
        onPress={ () => { this.setState({selectedSection: 'home' }) } }
        ...
      />
      <MenuItem
        title="Stories"
        onPress={ () => { this.setState({selectedSection: 'stories' }) } }
        ...
      />
    </View>
  )
}
```

And the main view should then display the unique navigator for each section:

```
contentView() {
  switch( this.state.selectedSection ) {

    case 'home':
      return (
        <NavigatorIOS
          initialRoute={{
            component: HomeComponent,
            title: 'HOME',
          }}
        />
      )

    case 'stories':
      return (
        <NavigatorIOS
          initialRoute={{
            component: StoriesComponent,
            title: 'STORIES',
          }}
        />
      )
  }
}
```

Unfortunately this is not working at all because I only get the initial Navigator (initial state.selectedSection = 'home') to show up but on section change the Navigator remains the same instead og beeing replaced by the other (e.g. stories) navigator.

Answer (score 0):

I kind of solved it myself using the following (DrawerLayout remains from my original question):

```
import NavigatorHome from './NavigatorHome'
import NavigatorStories from './NavigatorStories'

const navigationView = (
  <View>
    <MenuItem
      title="Home"
      onPress={ () => { this.refs.navigator.jumpTo(mainRoutes[0]) } }
      ...
    />
    <MenuItem
      title="Stories"
      onPress={ () => { this.refs.navigator.jumpTo(mainRoutes[1) } }
      ...
    />
  </View>
)

const mainRoutes = [
  {
    component: NavigatorHome,
  },
  {
    component: NavigatorStories,
  },
]

const contentView = () => {
  return (
    <Navigator
      ref="navigator"
      initialRoute={ mainRoutes[0] }
      initialRouteStack={ mainRoutes }
      renderScene={ (route, navigator) => {
        return <route.component />
      }}
      configureScene={ (route, routeStack) => Navigator.SceneConfigs.FadeAndroid }
      style={ styles.content }
    />
  )
}
```

// NavigatorHome.js

```
import React from 'react'
import {
  NavigatorIOS,
} from 'react-native'

import FirstScreenInHome from './FirstScreenInHome'

const NavigatorHome = ({
  rootNav,
}) => {
  return(
    <NavigatorIOS
      initialRoute={{
        component: FirstScreenInHome,
        title: 'Welcome to the first screen',
      }}
    />
  )
}

export default NavigatorHome
```